# Legal issue of bitcoin investment in the US as a foreigner

Tags: trading, buy-bitcoins, government

So after China banned CNY <=> bitcoin trading, I plan to invest in bitcoin with my USD. My plan is:

1. exchange USD with CNY (by wire probably)
2. Buy bitcoins with USD
3. Sell bitcoins for USD.
4. Exchange back to CNY (by wire).

In the above proccess, is there any legal issue against money laundering law of the US?

Comment: I agree that this is a good and relevant question but believe it should rightly be answered on [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com) provided it is suitable there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking for legal advice.  Consult a lawyer familiar with the topic and jurisdictions in question.